# Tube and Cylinder causing problems for 3D printing!

Tags: bugs, graphics3d, 3d-printing

The following code generates a 3D graphic for a crystallographic structure. But when `Tube` is used to link the atoms, they are left out of the 3D printing previewer. `Cylinder` does generate the links, but crashes the Kernel when sent to a 3D service. Any ways to make the structure?

3D printing of structure (unit cells)

```
latposCePd20 = 
  {{1.941555`, 1.49574903880332`, 1.14428425`}, 
   {1.941555`, 9.38828496119668`, 3.4328527499999995`}, 
   {0.`, 6.9377660388033195`, 1.14428425`}, 
   {0.`, 3.9462679611966798`, 3.4328527499999995`}}

latposRhPd20 = 
  {{1.941555`, 4.48312467969212`, 1.14428425`},
   {1.941555`, 6.400909320307879`, 3.4328527499999995`}, 
   {0.`, 9.92514167969212`, 1.14428425`}, 
   {0.`, 0.95889232030788`, 3.4328527499999995`}}

aPd20 = 3.88311`
bPd20 = 10.884034`
cPd20 = 4.577137`

select$radius$center[a_, r1_, r2_] := 
  Module[{b = {1.941555`, 1.49574903880332`, 1.14428425`}},
    If[r1 <= EuclideanDistance[a, b] <= r2, a, Nothing]]

select$radius$relative[{b_, a_}, r1_, r2_] := 
  Module[{},
    If[r1 <= EuclideanDistance[a, b] <= r2, {b, a}, Nothing]]

Ce$pos = 
  select$radius$center[#, 0, 7.5] & /@ 
    Flatten[
      Table[
        {i aPd20, j bPd20, k cPd20} + # & /@ latposCePd20, 
        {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, {k, -2, 2}],
      3];

Rh$pos = 
  select$radius$center[#, 0, 7.5] & /@ 
    Flatten[
      Table[
        {i aPd20, j bPd20, k cPd20} + # & /@ latposRhPd20, 
        {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}, {k, -2, 2}], 
      3];

tubes = 
  Flatten[
    Table[
      select$radius$relative[{Ce$pos[[i]], Rh$pos[[j]]}, 0, 3.5], 
      {i, 1, Length[Ce$pos]}, {j, 1, Length[Rh$pos]}], 
     1];

diagram3D = 
  Graphics3D[
    {Blue, Sphere[#, 2.5/3] & /@ Ce$pos, 
     Red, Sphere[#, 1.8/3] & /@ Rh$pos, 
     White, Tube[#, 0.2] & /@ tubes},
    ViewPoint -> {20, 0, 0}, Boxed -> False]

Printout3D[diagram3D]
```

generates a graphic with unlinked spheres!

[image]

In the previewer (MacOSX 10.13.2 High Sierra MMA 11.2.0.0) I get this:

[image]

It crashes IMaterialise (says there is an error) and Sculpteo gives

[image]

Comment: I added the bug tag. Doesn't help you at the moment but maybe it raises the attention of some other users.

Comment: The code seems to work okay in 11.2 on Windows 10, this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE1QZ.png)

Comment: couldn't you come up with a smaller example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: It works for smaller unit cells `select$radius$center[#, 0, 5.5] ` but not for these numbers `select$radius$center[#, 0, 7.5]` and higher...

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but an extended comment:

Which version of MMA are you using? I use 11.0.1 for macos and with

```
a = Printout3D[diagram3D]; 
Import[Cases[a, _File, \[Infinity]][[1]][[1]]]
```

I obtain this:

[image]

However, Mathematica opens Xcode as previewer for that `stl` file and Xcode shows the model in white on white background so that it is hard to see...

Comment: On my computer, I don't get the tubes even after XCode installation!

Comment: So, I would say, this is a bug then. Please, report it to Wolfram Research. There have been several changes for `MeshRegion` between version 11.0.1 and 11.2, in particular for the function `RegionUnion`. Not all changes were for the better, though. I tried to use `RegionUnion` on your `Sphere`s and `Cylinder`s, and to apply `DiscretizeRegion` and `Printout3D`  afterwards. But the result was shabby. In version 11.2, you can try to discretize the spheres and cylinders first and apply `RegionUnion` afterwards. (I cannot try that with version 11.0.1).

Comment: When I DiscretizeGraphics on only the tubes I get:Tube::opset: Option VertexNormals is not set in Options[Tube].

Comment: Righty, that's why I suggested to use `Cylinder`.

Comment: With Cylinders, I cannot DiscretizeGraphics either it says: The function DiscretizeGraphics is not implemented for "the graphic". With the mouse over the error, I get: "Skeleton is not a Graphics3D primitive or directive". The number of cylinders in the little box appear incomplete.

Comment: Try to map `DiscretizeRegion` onto a list of `Spheres` and `Cylinders` and not apply `DiscretizeGraphics ` to a `Graphics3D` object. As we have learned, `DiscretizeGraphics` is broken in your version of Mathematica.

Comment: I could  `DiscretizeRegion[RegionUnion[Sequence @@ (Sphere[#, 1.8/3] & /@ Rh$pos)]]` and even with `Cone`, but it fails with `Tube` and `Cylinder`.

Comment: And what happens if you swap `DiscretizeRegion` and `RegionUnion`? (Unfortunately, I cannot test this.)

Comment: If I swap `RegionUnion[DiscretizeRegion[]]` I get an error message (Option expected beyond position 2) because DiscretizeRegion has to operate on a Region of some sort.

Comment: You have to `Map` onto the list of regions (cylinders, for example).

Comment: I get nice spheres all within a compact region with `RegionUnion[Sequence @@ (DiscretizeRegion[#] & /@ (Sphere[#, 2.5/3] & /@ Ce$pos))]` and I can combine the Rh$pos spheres with a `RegionUnion`. With `Cylinders` and `Cone` I get a `BooleanRegion` on a list of disjointed `Cylinders` (the global reference is lost).

Comment: Phew. Sorry. Then I don't know...